# How to visualize splunk events as column chart

Tags: json, charts, splunk, splunk-dashboard

How could I visualize json data from several Splunk events as column chart?

The json I get each time the app logs data to Splunk has the following structure:

```json
{
    "monat": "2020-06-01",
    "duration": 512,
    "herkunft": "abc"
}
```

The column chart should count the equal `monat` fields and put them in the same column. If there is a new month (`monat` field) a new column should be created.

I am struggling to define the search term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a search that returns those fields, adding the `chart` command should do it.  You'll then need to switch to the "Visualization" tab and select the desired graph type.

```
... | chart count by monat
```

Comment: Is it possible to stack the column chart by a second property `herkunft`? I want to stack all different `herkunft` values of a `monat`. How do I have to define the term? I tried with `... | chart count by monat | fields monat herkunft` but the chart I got was not what I wanted.

Comment: Try `...| chart count by monat, herkunft`.